# How to filter an array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

*Guys, please don't answer me to use a JavaScript library to solve this problem, I'm using VanillaJS.*

Suppose I have an array with 10,000 string records, same as following:

```
var arr = [
  'John',
  'Foo',
  'Boo',
  ...
  'Some',
  'Beer'
];
```

Please note that the array doesn't follow any sort.

Now, I want to find items with `oo` in the text, what is the best way to do? Should I populate a new array or just `pop` items that don't match with the criteria?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_filter.htm

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/UCksL/

Comment: There are several conditions to choose algo say : short length / long array .. etc

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev could you please expand your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, which will create a new array with all the elements that passes the condition.

```
arr.filter(function(x){ return x.indexOf ('oo') > -1});
```

If you want to use filter method in every browser you could add the polyfill method (see link) in your code.

---

Another option (slightly faster) with basic javascript would be:

Looping trough the array with a simple for loop and test on your condition.

```
var filtered = [];
for(var i=0, length=arr.length; i<length; i++){
   var current = arr[i]; 
   if(current.indexOf('oo') > -1){ 
      filtered.push(current);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is `> 0`?

Answer (score 2):

my approch

**forEach function**

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
```

**partial function**

```
function asArray(quasiArray, start) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = (start || 0); i < quasiArray.length; i++)
        result.push(quasiArray[i]);
    return result;
}

function partial(func) {
    var fixedArgs = asArray(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        return func.apply(null, fixedArgs.concat(asArray(arguments)));
    };
}
```

**contains method for String obj**

```
if (!String.prototype.contains) {
    String.prototype.contains = function (arg) {
        return !!~this.indexOf(arg);
    };
}
```

**filter function:**

```
function filter(test, array) {
    var result = [];
    forEach(array, function(element) {
        if (test(element))
            result.push(element);
    });
    return result;
}
```

**test function for test array items**

```
function test(key, el) {
    return el.contains(key);
}
```

finally

```
filter(partial(test, 'oo'), arr);
```

Comment: Parcham balas :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NO shortcuts ( p.s. you said *I want to find items* , not filter - hence my answer)

simple loop :

```
var g=arr.length; //important since you have big array
for( var i=0;i<g;i++)
{
 if ( g[i].indexOf('oo')>-1)  
  {
     console.log(g[i]);
  }
}
```

If you want to filter (without polyfill)

```
  var g=arr.length; //important since you have big array
  var h=[];
    for( var i=0;i<g;i++)
    {
     if ( g[i].indexOf('oo')>-1)  
      {
         h.push(g[i]);
      }
    }

    //do something with h
```

Comment: So you're saying I should create a temp array and push items into it, right?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani added that info

Comment: The title specifies `filter`. His use of `find` was probably mistaken as he later asks if he create new arrays, etc.

Comment: @EpicDavi Could be. that's why I added the other solution

Comment: Are you sure it's the best way to filter an array with a lot of items? I mean, isn't it better to `pop`ing the mismatch items?

Comment: you can't pop unmatching items only. you pop an item . it could be right or wrong. that's why pop doesnt help here :-)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way, use `forEach`:

```
var result = [];
arr.forEach(function (value) {
    if (value.indexOf('oo') !== -1) {
        result.push(value);
    }
});
```

or `map`:

```
var result = [];
arr.map(function (value) {
    if (value.indexOf('oo') !== -1) {
        result.push(value);
    }
});
```